# Pause progress of ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, objectanimator

I'm implementing a custom view which draws some kind ProgressBar view, taking two views as parameters (origin and destination). Like this:

[image]

This is the complete class:

```
class BarView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,
                                    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                    defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var valueAnimator: ObjectAnimator? = null
    private lateinit var path: Path

    private val pathMeasure = PathMeasure()
    private var pauseProgress: Int = dip(40)

    var progress = 0f
        set(value) {
            field = value.coerceIn(0f, pathMeasure.length)
            invalidate()
        }

    private var originPoint: PointF? = null
    private var destinationPoint: PointF? = null

    private val cornerEffect = CornerPathEffect(dip(10).toFloat())

    private val linePaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = dip(10f).toFloat()
        color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.darker_gray)
        pathEffect = cornerEffect
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)

        if (progress < pathMeasure.length) {
            val intervals = floatArrayOf(progress, pathMeasure.length - progress)
            val progressEffect = DashPathEffect(intervals, 0f)
            linePaint.pathEffect = ComposePathEffect(progressEffect, cornerEffect)
        }

        canvas.drawPath(path, linePaint)
    }

    object PROGRESS : Property<BarView, Float>(Float::class.java, "progress") {
        override fun set(view: BarView, progress: Float) {
            view.progress = progress
        }

        override fun get(view: BarView) = view.progress
    }

    private fun startAnimator() {
        valueAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, PROGRESS, 0f, pathMeasure.length).apply {
            duration = 500L
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        }
        setPauseListener()
        valueAnimator!!.start()
    }

    fun resume() {
        valueAnimator!!.resume()
    }

    fun reset() {
        startAnimator()
    }

    fun setPoints(originView: View, destinationView: View) {
        originPoint = PointF(originView.x + originView.width / 2, 0f)
        destinationPoint = PointF(destinationView.x + destinationView.width / 2, 0f)

        setPath()
        startAnimator()
    }

    private fun setPath() {
        path = Path()
        path.moveTo(originPoint!!.x, originPoint!!.y)
        path.lineTo(destinationPoint!!.x, destinationPoint!!.y)

        pathMeasure.setPath(path, false)
    }

    private fun setPauseListener() {
        valueAnimator!!.addUpdateListener(object : ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
            override fun onAnimationUpdate(valueAnimator: ValueAnimator?) {
                val progress = valueAnimator!!.getAnimatedValue("progress") as Float
                if (progress > pauseProgress) {
                    valueAnimator.pause()
                    this@BarView.valueAnimator!!.removeUpdateListener(this)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

What im trying to do is to pause the animation at a specific progress, 40dp in this case:

```
private fun setPauseListener() {
    valueAnimator!!.addUpdateListener(object : ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
        override fun onAnimationUpdate(valueAnimator: ValueAnimator?) {
            val progress = valueAnimator!!.getAnimatedValue("progress") as Float
            if (progress > pauseProgress) {
                valueAnimator.pause()
                this@BarView.valueAnimator!!.removeUpdateListener(this)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

But the animations have different speeds since the views have different path lengths, and all of them have to finish in 500ms. They are not pausing at the same distance from the origin:

[image]

I tried switching from a `LinearInterpolator` to a `AccelerateInterpolator`, to make the start of the animation slower, but i'm still not satisfied with the results.

[image]

The next step for me, would be to try to implement a custom `TimeInterpolator` to make the animation start speed the same no matter how long the path is on each view, but I cannot wrap my head arrow the maths to create the formula needed.

```
valueAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, PROGRESS, 0f, pathMeasure.length).apply {
        duration = 500L
        interpolator = TimeInterpolator { input ->
            // formula here
        }
    }
```

Any help with that would be well received. Any suggestions about a different approach. What do you think?

Comment: Do you need well designed solution which is suppose to be maintainable or a hack will do as well ?

Comment: ++ You don't event need custom view for that probably Determinate progress bar will get the job done see the [link](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html#linear-progress-indicators) for details

Answer (score 0):

1) As I mentioned I would use determinate ProgressBar and regulate bar width by maximum amount of progress, assigned to certain view

2) I would use ValueAnimator.ofFloat with custom interpolator and set progress inside it

3) I would extend my custom interpolator from AccelerateInterpolator to make it look smthng like this:

```
class CustomInterpolator(val maxPercentage: Float) : AccelerateInterpolator(){
    override fun getInterpolation(input: Float): Float {
        val calculatedVal = super.getInterpolation(input)
        return min(calculatedVal, maxPercentage)
    }
}
```

where maxPercentage is a fraction of view width (from 0 to 1) you bar should occupy

Hope it helps